# Acessar projeto de pasta específica

Tags: angular, htaccess

Tenho a seguinte url

http://localhost/meuApp

Feita no angular

O meu arquivo .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /meuApp/index.html
```

Gostaria que dentro desse diretório eu guardesse os arquivos dentro uma subpasta chamada: frontend

Ficando assim:

```
minhaApp
      |__ frontend
```

Mas que continuasse chamando assim: localhost/meuApp

Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas ele faz é redirecionar para o subdiretório e voltar e não é isso o que eu quero

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /meuApp

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/meuApp/frontend
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/meuApp/exclude-file1\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/meuApp/exclude-file2\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/meuApp/exclude-dir
RewriteRule (.*) frontend/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: E vai ter algo que deve ser acessado fora da subpasta?

Comment: Só os clientes que acessarão o sistema

Comment: Tá mas tem arquivos estáticos e scripts fora da pasta front-end acessiveis via URL? As regras de negócio não interessam ainda, a pergunta é sobre o comportamento das urls

Comment: Não. Os arquivos ficam tudo dentro da pasta frontend

Comment: Ok, vou repetir a pergunta, porque a cada vez que responde faz entender uma coisas diferente... O que esta FORA da pasta frontend precisa ser acessivel via URL de alguma forma ou outras pastas?

Comment: Não. Não tem nada fora da pasta frontend. O que possivelmente vá ter é a pasta backend que será em NodeJS, mas não terão arquivos que serão necessários acessar via URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta não usar `RewriteCond` antes, basta apontar tudo para `./frontend` diretamente e depois na proxima regra você escreve as "rotas" do Angular, assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona tudo
RewriteRule ^ frontend/ [L]

# Se estiver dentro de frontend checa se o arquivo existe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# se for uma rota direciona para meuApp/index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Isto se a sua estrutura fora:

```
./public_html
  └───.htaccess
  └───frontend
      ├───images
      └───index.html (do angular)
```

Note que não tem as barras `/` na frente, o caminho é relativo, a não ser que você queira configurar a partir de outro ponto.

Deve usar o `[L]` para para a regra atual para que duas regras não se misturem. Não testei, mas na teoria é isto, se não funcionar você pode criar 2 .htaccess, assim:

```
./public_html
  ├───.htaccess
  └───frontend
      ├───images
      ├───.htaccess
      └───index.html (do angular)
```

Ficando o htaccess da public_html assim apenas (sem mais nada):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ frontend/ [L]
```

E o .htaccess dentro da frontend assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# se for uma rota direciona para index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: E caso eu quisesse colocar mais de um projeto dentro dessa pasta, mas chamando a url diferente: Por exemplo: http://192.168.1.1/meuapp e http://192.168.1.1/meuapp2, eu poderia reaproveitar o .htaccess?

Comment: @adventistaam ai depende, ambos apps vão usar o mesmo frontend?

Comment: Neste caso sim.. Ambos os projetos utilizarão o mesmo diretório `frontend`

Comment: @adventistaam não tem como aproveitar a estrutura então, teria que fazer de outra forma

Comment: Entendi.. Tudo bem. Mesmo assim obrigado pela solução. Ja ajudou bastante